# Fotorama container doesn't get its initial width after fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, slider, fotorama

on some actual project I use Fotorama a couple of times. I got it working perfectly on some part of the website (allowing fullscreen also).

Anyway, there is another template I need the slider into and there it has an odd behaviour that I can't fix and drives me mad. And it's about responsiveness.

It works well until I allow fullscreen. Fullscreen mode works well also, but then when I click to get out of the fullscreen mode, the div *fotorama_stage*

```
<div class="fotorama__stage" style="width: XXXpx; height: XXXpx;">
```

doesn't get its initial value back. It stays steched, leaving the image overflowing the display.

When I resize the window, the correct width value gets assigned into the DOM, and everything seems fine again. Can someone please tell me what I should look at ?